# GeoServer Transformation Function (Categorize) Problem

Tags: geoserver, sld, ogc

I'm trying run three filter functions(Recode,Categorize,Interpolate) described at the bottom of this page
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html

Recode and Interpolate works fine but Categorize throws me the following exception message. 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find function Categorize'

What could cause this problem ? Am I supposed to install a plugin on geoserver or what?

The official examples are on
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-tipstricks/transformation-func.html

Comment: what does the log file say?

Comment: @iant it says 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find function Categorize
 at org.geotools.filter.FunctionFinder.findFunction(FunctionFinder.java:104)
 at org.geotools.filter.FunctionFinder.findFunction(FunctionFinder.java:70)
 at org.geotools.filter.FilterFactoryImpl.function(FilterFactoryImpl.java:470)
 at org.geotools.filter.ExpressionDOMParser.expression(ExpressionDOMParser.java:394)
 at org.geotools.filter.ExpressionDOMParser.parseExpression(ExpressionDOMParser.java:102)

Answer (score 2):

The question is old, but I had the same issue. For me the problem was the style definition, I was missing the last value for the ranges; with respect to the example in the Geoserver documentation,

```
     <ogc:Literal>#87CEEB</ogc:Literal>
     <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
     <ogc:Literal>#FFFACD</ogc:Literal>
     <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
     <ogc:Literal>#F08080</ogc:Literal>   <!-- I was misisng a line :) -->
```